# Hibernate error with query "FOR XML PATH"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need some help

I'm using on my proyect Spring Boot, JPA Repositories and DB is SQL Server 2012; all of my repositories are working good but I've a problem excecuting the next query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT A_DOCUMENT FROM DOCUMENT WHERE C_DOCUMENT = ?1 FOR XML PATH('')", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> findAdocumentByCdocument(Integer cdocument);
```

I get the next error:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -16
>       at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:666) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.custom.JdbcResultMetadata.getHibernateType(JdbcResultMetadata.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(ScalarResultColumnProcessor.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:487) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2125) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]

Have any idea how can I excecute this query on JPA?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried with `List<String>` ?

Comment: @Saravana yes but I get the same error, I updated my question with the exception

Comment: @Miike what does the query return, can you post sample data?

Comment: It returns a temporal xml, the data is too long it doesn't fit here, the length is: 88516; on sql server console it works but with jpa i get the exception

Comment: can you try casting to text `CAST(A_DOCUMENT as text)` ?

Comment: Seems like the problem is the Hibernate team forgot to include `java.sql.Types.LONGNVARCHAR` support in the dialect, when they added `NVARCHAR` in `SQLServer2008Dialect`. You should file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Since the return type is not registered to `Hibernate` we are getting an exception, so try `CAST` your result to `text`

```
@Query(value = "SELECT CAST(A_DOCUMENT AS text) FROM DOCUMENT WHERE C_DOCUMENT = ?1 FOR XML PATH('')",
     nativeQuery = true)
List<String> findAdocumentByCdocument(Integer cdocument);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I get the same error, I think that the problem is that JDBC doesn't map my query on the SQLServer2012Dialect.
The field A_DOCUMENT is VARCHAR(MAX) and the content of the field exceeds the limit of a normal SELECT

Comment: Try changing it to clob or refine the output, is expected to have ~85k in a column

Comment: He is talking about "FOR XML PATH" not return type issue!!